# Redshift Upsert where staging has duplicate items

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift database set up that stores posts. Posts are defined as unique by their `post_id`, and all other fields can be variable.

I am using a staging table to do an equivalent `UPSERT` using the following query:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE posts_staging (LIKE posts);
COPY posts_staging (post_id,user_id,timestamp,votes,comments) FROM 's3://posts' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxx;aws_secret_access_key=yyyy' CSV;
DELETE FROM posts USING posts_staging WHERE posts.post_id = posts_staging.post_id;
INSERT INTO posts SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts_staging;
DROP TABLE posts_staging;
END;
```

Most of the time this works correctly, however I am noticing some duplicate values going into the table. I believe what is happening is that there is a possibility that the CSV uploaded has duplicate `post_ids`, but with different other fields (for example, differing numbers of likes), meaning the `DISTINCT` is inserting multiple of the same `post_id`. Is there a way to modify this query to only `INSERT` unique `post_ids`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift, alas does not support `distinct on`.  But you can use `row_number()`:

```
INSERT INTO posts
    SELECT . . .
    FROM (SELECT ps.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY post_id) as seqnum
          FROM posts_staging ps
         ) ps
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You will need to list out the columns being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your following query, distinct * may return duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO posts SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts_staging;
```

You should be removing duplicates from post_staging first before upsert.